# cookie that works with all folders

Tags: cookies

I have a cookie that is on every page of my site. It works fine when the address is like this.
http://mydomain.com/index.html or whatever.

but when I have a page that is in a folder like this
http://mydomain.com/folder/page.html

instead of using the cookie that I have set for all the other pages it creates a new cookie just for that folder. Is there any way to keep the same cookie for all folders? Or I'm I just doing something terrible wrong?

Thanks

my code -- I have this in a external js. file

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var cookie = $.cookie('cookiename');
    if (cookie) {
    }
    else {
        $.cookie('cookiename', 'cookievalue');
    }
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.watevevever').click(function() {
    var va = $('#watev').css('display');
        if (va == 'none'){
            $('#watev').fadeIn("slow");
            $.cookie('cookiename', 'cookievalue');
        }
        else {
            $('#watev').fadeOut("slow");
            $.cookie('cookiename', 'cookievalue');
        }
    });
    var va = $.cookie('cookiename');
    if (va == 'cookievalue') {
        $('#watev').css("display","none");
    };
});
```

Comment: You don't show the code where you're setting and reading cookies, so there's no way to know what you're doing wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using [this plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/cookie) for jQuery (and its source is [here](http://plugins.jquery.com/files/jquery.cookie.js.txt)), it seems, by looking at the source, that you can pass some additional parameters as an object, as a third parameter to the `$.cookie` method.

For instance, from [this tutorial](http://www.stilbuero.de/2006/09/17/cookie-plugin-for-jquery/), you can add an expiration date :

```
$.cookie('the_cookie', 'the_value', { expires: 7 }); // set cookie with an expiration date seven days in the future
```

Looking at the source, you have this portion of code :

```
var path = options.path ? '; path=' + (options.path) : '';
var domain = options.domain ? '; domain=' + (options.domain) : '';
var secure = options.secure ? '; secure' : '';
```

So, I suppose you can use a "`path`" attribute in the object given as third parameter, like, for instance :

```
$.cookie('the_cookie', 'the_value', {path: '/'});
```

Of course, this '`/`' is if you want to set to cookie for every paths on your domain -- which seems to be the case.

You can probably also set some other options, like '`domain`', if you want to use subdomains, btw...

Answer (score 1):

```
$.cookie('the_cookie', 'the_value', { expires: 7, path: '/', domain: 'jquery.com', secure: true });
```

the optional parameters includes 'path' .. which should be '/'